# Robotframework can't identify the value of a list element when the index as a loop variable

Tags: list, variables, robotframework

This is my code in robotframework, i want to remove the $,K,M,B from the list, and i try like this

```
${testList}    create list    a$    bK    cM
FOR    ${index}    IN RANGE    0    5
    ${testList}[${index}]    remove string    ${testList}[${index}]    $    K    M    B
END
```

but i get the error log : **No keyword with name '${testList}[${index}]' found.**
i confirm the string library is imported successfully
Am I doing something wrong? why robot cannot read the value?
Python version is 3.7.5 and ride version is 1.7.4.2

Updated i found a solution like this

```
    ${TestList}    create list    a$    bK    cM
    FOR    ${index}    IN RANGE    0    3
        ${value}    remove string    ${TestList}[${index}]    $    K    M    B
        set list value    ${TestList}    ${index}    ${value}
    END
    log    ${TestList}
```

But i still don't understand why the first solution went wrong..

Answer (score 0):

The first one failed because it expects either a keyword or an empty variable to be filled with the results from a following keyword in the first position, like so:

```
 This is a keyword

 ${value}    remove string    etc.
```

However what you gave it in your first example was

```
${testList}[${index}]    remove string    ${testList}[${index}]
```

which is neither.